# Duda laravel eloquent sql

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Soy nuevo en laravel y tengo un par de problemas acerca de `eloquent`.

Tengo el siguiente código.

```
$usuario = DB::table('user')
    ->select('user.id','user.name', 'user.email')
    ->join('user_dep', 'user_dep.user_id', '=', 'user.id')
    ->where('user_dep.dep_id', '=',30)
    ->get();
```

No me aparece error de sintaxis alguno, pero cuando uso un `foreach` para acceder a los datos en una tabla

```
.....
foreach($usuario as $us)
....
<td>{{$us->name}}</td>
....
```

toda la tabla me aparece en blanco. ¿alguna idea de qué puedo hacer?.

Cuando uso `$usuario = user::all();` no tengo problemas para acceder a la información pero ahora necesito segmentarla y estoy teniendo problemas.

Comment: Haz un `dd($usuario)` y comprueba que contiene lo que esperas, es posible que te este devolviendo 0 resultados.

Comment: si estas invocando el face DB  de este mod use DB; en la parte superior de los namespaces?

Comment: usa... $us['name'] . a ver si te funciona

Comment: Deberías usar el Modelo, al igual que en User::all() Para ello usa las relaciones de eloquent https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships Ya que DB devuelve un array y no objetos.

Answer (score 1):

Aségurate que $usuario sea un objeto y no un arreglo. Puedes hacerlo con:

```
var_dump($usuario);
die();
```

En caso de ser un arreglo tendrás que usar el ciclo de la siguiente manera:

```
foreach($usuario[0] as $us)
{
    ...
}
```

No olvides validar que $usuario no sea null antes de colocar su índice.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Si te fijas, estás haciendo dos queries de manera diferente.

Cuando haces esto:

```php
$users = DB::table('user')
    ->select('user.id','user.name', 'user.email')
    ->join('user_dep', 'user_dep.user_id', '=', 'user.id')
    ->where('user_dep.dep_id', '=',30)
    ->get();
```

lo haces mediante el [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries) de Laravel. Este tipo de consultas trae como resultado un `array`. Es por eso que para acceder a los atributos de cada elemento lo tienes que hacer como en cualquier otro `array`:

```php
.....
foreach($users as $user)
....
<td>{{ $user['name'] }}</td>
....
```

Por otro lado, lado cuando consultas de este modo:

```php
$users = User::all();
```

Estás utilizando [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-collections). Por lo que el resultado es una colección de objetos (`User`). Esto te permite consultar a los atributos como si fueran métodos (gracias a los métodos 'mágicos' de PHP). Es por eso que al hacer lo siguiente recibes los datos:

```php
.....
foreach($users as $user)
....
<td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
....
```

---

Ahora, si lo que deseas es hacer tu consulta mediante Eloquent, tienes que hacerlo a través de las [relaciones](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships) definidas en tus modelos.

Por el nombre de tu table intermedia (`user_dep`) asumo que tienes una tabla/modelo `Department`. En ese modelo puedes definir la relación de la siguiente manera:

**app\Department.php**

```php
// ...
public function users() // el método al que llamaremos
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class);
}
```

De modo que tu consulta sería la siguiente:

```php
$department = Department::find(30);
$users = $department->users;
// o de manera resumida:
// $users = Department::find(30)->users;
```

Permitiendote usar estos objetos como lo querías inicialmente:

```php
.....
foreach($users as $user)
....
<td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
....
```